# Can I execute the make command only on selected lines?

Tags: visual-mode, make

Let's say I have the following script:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install jq
sudo apt install jo
```

If I use the command `:set makeprg=bash\ % | make` inside Vim, the system will ask me my password and then it'll execute this entire script. However, I'd like to find a way of executing only the lines that I select... Let's say I go to the third line inside this file and I press `V` to select only the third line, is there any way of making Vim execute interactively only this line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple:

- `:[range]w !{program}` uses a range to only write selected lines as standard input. This doesn’t work if you need to run it differently.
- `!` is similar but replaces the range with the output.
- Delete the non-interesting lines, write the file, and run it. Then undo and write again.
- You could probably make an operator and visual mapping that ran `bash -c …`, but you would want to think about using single quotes, escaping them in the arguments, and maybe even joining lines together.
- Run `:terminal` for a shell and copy-paste
- Run `:terminal <C-r>=getline('.')` to directly run the current line (no shell)

Comment: Interesting that `!` doesn't require saving the file as it usually does when I'm working with selected lines. I didn't manage to make `:[range]w !{program}` work though. does the `range` word mean the line numbers? What does the `{program}` syntax do? I've tried stuff like `:[4-7]w !{%}`, `:[4-7]w !{program}` and the literal `:[range]w !{program}`... But it's not clear to me how I'd use it...

Comment: Those are placeholders @raylight   See `:help range`. Replace the curly braces too with your program name (eg bash)